# Does Clickatell support personalized SMS in their SMS API?

Tags: sms, sms-gateway, clickatell

Can I send a pesonalized sms message in **Clickatell SMS API**?

I cannot find any documentation on how to do that.

Comment: you should contact their support staff.

Answer (score 2):

Yes - you can personalize SMS messages in Clickatell SMS API.

If you have an older account (Developer's Central, registered before November 2016) then you would first need to buy SMS credits. Once a purchase is made, you can personalize your messages.

If you have the newer Platform account, you will need make a deposit into your Clickatell account, which will allow you to personalize your messages.

Comment: Do you mind sharing the link to the documentation/site where can I get more information on how to personalize SMS messages? The only thing in their documentation are very simple examples. I am using platform account by the way.

Comment: Hi jeicoo,

Just to check if I understand your query - are you referring to unlocking functionality to send what you want, instead of a generic test? Or are you asking how to change the Sender that the user sees when the message arrives?

Comment: It seems that you did not understand my query, I am not asking for both of them. I am asking how to send a personalized message, something like "Hello {name}" so that every recipients will receive message with their name included, in one API call.

Answer (score 0):

You can send personalized messages be editing the **content** string in your request.

When using the REST API, in the body of your request:

```
{
"content": "Personalized message", 
"to": [""]
}
```

When making an HTTP request:

```
https://platform.clickatell.com/messages/http/send?apiKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx==&to=xxxxxxxxxxx&content=Personalized+message
```

These are the links to the documentation for sending messages with [REST](https://www.clickatell.com/developers/api-documentation/rest-api-send-message/) and [HTTP](https://www.clickatell.com/developers/api-documentation/http-api-send-message/)